# Apache Vs. lighthttpd?

Tags: apache, lighttpd

I've recently bought a VDS server with 768MB RAM. All of my RAM is being eaten by Apache(286MB). As lighthttpd is lighter and needs less memory I want to switch to that. I just want to make sure I miss nothing in between. Is there any major differences between them that I'm unaware of?
[image]
I appreciate in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest thing you have to know is that lighttpd doesn't have the same URL rewriting flexibility as Apache. Any URL rewriting has to be put directly into the lighttpd configuration files as opposed to the .htaccess files ubiquitous in Apache installs.

Also, PHP installation is not quite as straight forward on lighttpd as in Apache because there's no module for it. Lighttpd uses the fastcgi version of PHP. Not that it's a bad thing, just different.

I've used lighttpd with PHP to run the control front end for an on-hold music player in our office and it works quite famously.

Answer (score 1):

You could use lighthttpd, squid or even nginx as a proxy to try and see if proxying lowers the overall resources being used.   nginx would probably be your best overall replacement for apache2